# how to partially "link" highlighting groups?

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting, vim-syntax-highlighting

I'm trying to do this on my `.vimrc`:

```
hi link SyntasticErrorLine SignColumn
hi link SyntasticErrorSign SignColumn
hi SyntasticErrorSign guifg=red ctermfg=red
```

What I want is to have the `SyntasticErrorSign` highlighting group with the same background as `SignColumn` but with custom foreground colors.

Vim docs says:

> - As soon as you use a ":highlight" command for a linked group, the link is   removed.

So, the way I'm doing it won't work anyway, is there a way to achieve that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[@Kent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18775404) was good, but it seems there's a problem with `synIDattr` when one doesn't pass the `mode` argument, it fails to return the attribute in GUI mode (gvim). I've learned this from [vim-arline plugin sources](https://github.com/bling/vim-airline/blob/master/autoload/airline/highlighter.vim#L17).

I've solved my problem with:

```
hi link SyntasticErrorLine SignColumn

exec 'hi SyntasticErrorSign guifg=red ctermfg=red' .
            \' guibg=' . synIDattr(synIDtrans(hlID('SignColumn')), 'bg', 'gui') .
            \' ctermbg=' . synIDattr(synIDtrans(hlID('SignColumn')), 'bg', 'cterm')
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to "steal" some hl-attribute value from other group, you don't have to `link`, you just get the value for your own usage.

For your problem, try to add this line into your .vimrc file.

```
exec 'hi SyntasticErrorSign guifg=red ctermfg=red ' . (has("gui_running")? 'guibg=':'ctermbg=') . synIDattr(hlID('SignColumn'),'bg')
```

The line sets `fg(gui and cterm)` of `SyntasticErrorSign` group as `red`, and uses the same bg color of group `SignColumn`, depends on you are in `gvim` or `vim`. I think it should be what you are looking for.

For those functions, you could just `:h xxx()` to get detailed information.

Comment: hi, really, almost there, but in gvim, it's not working, only in terminal. In gvim `synIDattr(hlID('SignColumn'),'bg')` is not returning a value for `guibg`, it's empty. Any tip?

Comment: it seems there's a problem for `gvim` when this is executed from `.vimrc`, executing the expression from command line returns the background...

Comment: @chico sorry, I didn't give it a test. I thought if the `mode` was not given, the value of attr of current mode will be returned. that's why I had the `gui_running` check.

Answer (score 0):

This does what you want:

```
hi SyntasticErrorSign guifg=red ctermfg=red
hi! link SyntasticErrorSign SignColumn
```

The `!` forces the link even though you already have attributes set on the highlight group.